# Javascript: How to use Reduce to get New Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I'm new to coding, so this might be a simple question but one that I can't understand. I have an array of all the best pies each with their own price:

```
pieArr = [blueberry, strawberry, pumpkin, apple]
```

I want to create an array of objects that shows the total of the shopping cart depending on the price of the pie, and someone here on stack overflow recommended I use reduce.

This is what I have so far:

```
var total = 0;

const totalArr = pieArr.reduce((totalPrice, pie) => {
  if ( pie === "blueberry") {
    total += 2.5;
    totalPrice.push({["cartTotal"]:total});
    return totalPrice;
  }
 else if (pie === "apple") {
   total += 2;
   totalPrice.push({["cartTotal"]:total});
   return totalPrice;
 }, 
 [])};
```

What I want the end result to be is a new array of objects that keeps adding the new totals:

```
[{cartTotal:2.5},{cartTotal:4.5}]
```

The new array of objects get created, but the total doesn't get added up, so it ends up with total being 0 both times:

```
[{cartTotal: 0},{cartTotal: 0}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `const total = 0;` Er, `const`, you sure? Also `const total = total + 2.5;` is invalid syntax, the code shouldn't run in the first place, I'd think? (Also, you probably want to `return totalPrice` when the first `if` condition is fulfilled as well)

Comment: In `const total = total + 2.5;` you’re declaring and reading your variable at the same time. Note that the outer `const total = 0;` is overshadowed here. Did you really mean to `const`-declare this? Where’s the `}` for the `else if`? Are you sure, you’re returning a value in both cases?

Comment: oh ok, so I fixed the const total, and added the return to the first if statement. however, it still doesn't change the total, any other ideas?

Comment: You should not use `const` if you are changing that variable. And let `total` be defined outside `reduce` operation. This way total will not be initializing after one iteration of reduce operation.

Comment: thanks CertainPerformance, Xufox, and @Meet Zaveri. I understood now what you meant by not using const if I'm changing a variable. the function works when I changed it to a var

Comment: You can use `var` or `let` unless you want immutable variable.

Answer (score 4):

A nice way to do this is to have a price lookup like:

```
let piePrices = {
    blueberry: 2.25,
    strawberry: 1.5, 
    pumpkin: 3,
    apple: 2
}
```

Then you can use that in `map()` (which is nicer than `reduce()` if you're just making an array from an array) without all the `if/else` noise:

```js
let piePrices = {
    blueberry: 2.25,
    strawberry: 1.5, 
    pumpkin: 3,
    apple: 2
}

let pieArr = ['blueberry', 'strawberry', 'pumpkin', 'apple']

let total = 0
let totalPrice = pieArr.map(pie =>  ({cartTotal: total += piePrices[pie]}))

console.log(totalPrice)
```

Comment: Mark you structured it nice. By having lookup object!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const total = 0;
let pieArr = ['blueberry', 'strawberry', 'pumpkin', 'apple']
const totalArr = pieArr.reduce((totalPrice, pie) => {
  let foundPie = totalPrice.find(x => x.name === pie) || {name: pie, total: 0};
  
 if ( pie === "blueberry") {
    foundPie.total += 2.5;
 }
 else if (pie === "apple") {
   foundPie.total += 2;
 }
 
 if(!totalPrice.some(x=>x.name === pie)){
   totalPrice.push(foundPie)
 }
  return totalPrice;
}, []);

console.log(totalArr)
```

I would recommend to add another attribute `name` for clearer picture. while we `reducing`, find the pie from accumulated `totalPrice` array, then do the summation, and do a checking if to push element to accumulated array